# plotly legend 2 variables

Tags: r, legend, plotly, bubble-chart

The help page for plotly has a nice example of different bubble charts that can be created using plotly in R. In the final example the colour of the different bubbles indicate a nominal or categorical variable (in this example continents) and the size of the bubbles indicate the continuous variable population size. However, the latter variable (population size) is mentioned neither in the legend nor anywhere else in the graph. Is it possible to have two indicators/variables (no idea to actually call these) in the legend? One with for the different colours indicating a categorical variable and one for different sizes indicating the size of a variable [(a little bit like the old style population estimates of cities on maps, see added image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oBjPm.gif)

https://plot.ly/r/bubble-charts/